# how to use Digest authentication in android?

Tags: android

I am creating an Android app where I am authenticating username/password through a server.Initially server was implementing `Basic` authentication so my code was working fine but now server has changed to `Digest` authentication so my old code is not working.

What changes should do make for using `Digest` authentication?

My code is as follows:

```
private boolean authenticateUser() 

{

   try 
   {
        String url_str = "http://serverweb.com/checkauthentication.php"; 

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url_str);

        Log.v("AUTHENTICATION URL = ", url_str);
        post.addHeader("Authorization","Basic "+getCredentials());
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response_body = client.execute(post, responseHandler);

        Log.v("SERVER RESPONSE DATA = ", response_body);

        XMLDataParser.parseXML(XMLDataParser.USER_INFORMATION_PARSER_CODE, response_body);

        List<Cookie> cookies = client.getCookieStore().getCookies();
        if (!cookies.isEmpty()) 
        {
         for (int i = 0; i < cookies.size(); i++) 
         {
           XMLData.cookie = cookies.get(i);
         }
        }

        return true;
    }
    catch (MalformedURLException mue) 
    { 
      Log.i("MalformedURLException", " "+mue.getMessage());
      displayDialog("User Does Not exist");
      return false;
    } 
    catch (IOException ioe) 
    { 
       Log.i("IOException", " "+ioe.getMessage());
       displayDialog("User Does Not exist");
       return false;
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    { 
       Log.i("Exception", " "+e.getMessage());
       displayDialog("Error");
       return false;
    }
}
private String getCredentials()
{
    String u=edit_username.getText().toString();
    String p=edit_password.getText().toString();

    Log.v("USER NAME = ",u);
    Log.v("PASSWORD = ",p);
    return(Base64.encodeBytes((u+":"+p).getBytes()));
}
```

Comment: your URL are not working

Comment: @scorpio This URL is not true one.

Answer (score 15):

You need to create a `HttpHost` and `HttpContext` object with required credentials and give it to execute method.

This is a sample code where your authentication is independent of backend auth. http client of android will take care of converting it to appropriate format. Check this sample code, this is only for your reference and not to be used directly in your code. :)

This code is in your activity:

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> httpTask = new TestHttpThread();
    httpTask.execute("test_url","test_user","test_password");
}
```

Sample `AsyncActivity`:

```
private class TestHttpThread extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
       if(params.length > 0){
            String url = params[0];
            String username = params[1];
            String password = params[2];

            try {
                AndroidHttpClient httpClient = AndroidHttpClient.newInstance("test user agent");

                URL urlObj = new URL(url);
                HttpHost host = new HttpHost(urlObj.getHost(), urlObj.getPort(), urlObj.getProtocol());
                AuthScope scope = new AuthScope(urlObj.getHost(), urlObj.getPort());
                UsernamePasswordCredentials creds = new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password);

                CredentialsProvider cp = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
                cp.setCredentials(scope, creds);
                HttpContext credContext = new BasicHttpContext();
                credContext.setAttribute(ClientContext.CREDS_PROVIDER, cp);

                HttpGet job = new HttpGet(url);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(host,job,credContext);
                StatusLine status = response.getStatusLine();
                Log.d(TestActivity.TEST_TAG, status.toString());
                httpClient.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: After using it I am getting EXCEPTION 
"This thread forbids HTTP requests" 
What can I do in this situation Please Help

Comment: you must be doing this request in main thread or ui thread. you should execute code in a async task or in a service

Comment: I am not able to get whether it is authenticating or not. if yes how can I get info return from server and sustain Session.

Comment: If authentication fails you should get error code as 401 otherwise 200 from server.  Log.d(TestActivity.TEST_TAG, status.toString()); this should tell what response code you got.

Comment: I am getting "HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily" it is redirecting me to other url but I am not getting how can I use redirected url to get info and also can use session id to maintain session.